# typescript not catching type mismatch (react TSX)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-tsx

TypeScript & React newbie here. Why does TypeScript not yell at me for `constructor(foo: string)` input type not matching `{foo: string}`? (Note: one of them is a string, the other an object.)

TypeScript will happily compile this, and of course the resulting code will blow up. I tried to turn on all the options tsconfig.json has to offer. I'm using typescript 2.5.3.

Is there any way, like typescript config, code change, or anything else to harden the code to avoid this? Any ideas appreciated, my goal is to write stable code.

import * as React from 'react';
    import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

```
class App extends React.Component<{ foo: string }, { foo: string }> {
    // expects string
    constructor(foo: string) {
        super();
        this.state = {
            foo: foo
        }
    }
    render() {
        return <div>{this.state.foo}</div>
    }
}

// Passes object { foo: string }
ReactDOM.render(<App foo="foo" />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

**EDIT**: simplified question

Comment: You do realize that this is not typescript, right?

Comment: @Amit, now that you say, I do, but I didn't realize at the time of asking. Thanks. So, then, any idea for a proper workflow for going JSX -> TS -> JS?

Comment: No, personally, I dislike react precisely for this reason. I find this syntax awkward and distracting.

Comment: @Amit, I'm looking for anything stable, so your suggestion of dropping TSX is in fact an improvement, thanks! Personally, I'd prefer to keep it if there is a way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll get the compiler complaints you're looking for if you remember to pass the `props` to `super()`.  This is just part of extending `React.Component`, and [should always be done.](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#constructor)

[image]

Comment: I wanted to give you a bounty, but apparently I can only do so after 23hrs. Documenting it here, to avoid further answers.

Answer (score 0):

Your concern :

```
// WRONG, to work, it should be:
//   constructor(props Props) {
constructor(foo: string, bar: string) {
  super();
}
```

is invalid because you can always inherit a class and provide your own constructor :

```
class A {
  constructor(a: number) { }
}

class B extends A {
  // ALLOWED
  constructor(b: string) {
    super(123)
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Actually, that's not my problem. It's that the constructor type mismatches that of the call `ReactDOM.render(<App foo="foo" bar="bar" />, root)`, which passes one object, not 2 strings.